# iPhone "Send My Current Location" to Twilio

Tags: python, iphone, location, twilio

I have a webhook that handles any sms messages sent to my Twilio number. However, this webhook only works if there is text in the message (there will be a body in the GET request).

Is it possible to parse a message if it is a location message? e.g. if I send my current location to my Twilio number and it redirects this message as a GET request to the webhook, could I possibly retrieve that location?

This is what my webhook receives if I send my current location on an iPhone:

`at=info method=GET path="/sms/?ToCountry=US&MediaContentType0=text/x-vcard&ToState=NJ&SmsMessageSid=MMde62b3369705a8f65f18abe5b7387c2b&NumMedia=1&ToCity=NEWARK&FromZip=07920&SmsSid=MMde62b3369705a8f65f18abe5b7387c2b&FromState=NJ&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=SOMERVILLE&Body=&FromCountry=US&To=%2B18627019482&ToZip=07102&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=MMde62b3369705a8f65f18abe5b7387c2b&AccountSid=ACe72df68a68db79d9a4ac6248df6e981e&From=%2B19083925806&MediaUrl0=https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe72df68a68db79d9a4ac6248df6e981e/Messages/MMde62b3369705a8f65f18abe5b7387c2b/Media/MEcd56717ce17f3a320b06c4ee11df2243&ApiVersion=2010-04-01"`

For comparison, here's a normal text message:

`at=info method=GET path="/sms/?ToCountry=US&ToState=NJ&SmsMessageSid=SM4767dabb915fae749c7d5b59d6f655a2&NumMedia=0&ToCity=NEWARK&FromZip=07920&SmsSid=SM4767dabb915fae749c7d5b59d6f655a2&FromState=NJ&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=SOMERVILLE&Body=Denver+E+union&FromCountry=US&To=%2B18627019482&ToZip=07102&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=SM4767dabb915fae749c7d5b59d6f655a2&AccountSid=ACe72df68a68db79d9a4ac6248df6e981e&From=%2B19083925806&ApiVersion=2010-04-01"`

In the normal sms message, I can parse out the `Body=Denver+E+union` to get the message, but I'm not sure you could do anything with the content of the location message.

If I can't get the location, what are some other easy ways I could send a parseable location?

Comment: Looking at the parameters being sent, it looks like there is a vcard being attached to the incoming message.  Its possible thats how the iphone sends that data, so to get it you'd need to download the vcard using the URL in the MediaUrl0 parameter and parse the file.  My experience in trying to do similar things is that different phone OS's and even OS versions do the "send me location" thing different ways, but none that I saw just send like a raw lat/long as a textual message.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem by creating a basic webpage which uses the HTML5 geolocation function to get lat/lng of the phone. It then submits coordinates to a php script via AJAX.

My server geocodes the employees location, calculates travelling time to next job and sends the customer an SMS with ETA information using the Twilio API.

You could bypass Twilio altogether and get your server to make the request direct to your webhook, or even via the AJAX call if it's all on the same domain. All depends what you are trying to achieve I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Devin points out in the comments, the location has been sent as a Vcard attached to the message. The URL, in the request as `MediaUrl0`, links to a Vcard that looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 10.3.2//EN
N:;YOUR_NAME’s Location;;;
FN:YOUR_NAME’s Location
item1.URL;type=pref:http://maps.apple.com/?ll=39.576254\,-104.865774&q=39.576254\,-104.865774
item1.X-ABLabel:map url
END:VCARD
```

As you can see, this comes with an Apple Maps URL, which is not the most useful thing. However, you can also see that the latitude and longitude of your location is included in the URL. You could conceivably parse this URL and extract the query parameters to get the location. As Devin points out though, this may well change across devices. You might want to test with a few different options to make sure this is scalable.

Let me know if that helps at all.